# How do I get curent value of text element via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have text input element and an event is fired on blur event and when user presses enter.

My problem is that if user inputs "foo" and presses enter `val()` function nevertheless returns null, after the blur event `val()` returns foo. As far as I understand it is due to the fact that value property of HTML input element is updated only when it looses focus. Could you please give me a work around.

Here is the exact code I use:

```
var meetmove_address_field_listener = function(e){
    var type = $(this).attr('data-marker-type');;
    var value = $(this).val();
    meetmove_map.geocodeAddress(type, value);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[data-type="name"]').blur(meetmove_address_field_listener);
    $('input[data-type="name"]').keypress(function(event){
        if (event.which == 13){
            event.preventDefault();
            meetmove_address_field_listener(event);
            return false; 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `.data('markerType')` to access the data attribute?

Comment: Well I just wasnt aware of it :)

Comment: You might also want to consider using a class selector to select your input fields - it's probably much faster than using an attribute selector. At least in modern browsers which have `getElementsByClassName()` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well really Sudahir answer solved my issue --- i was misusing $(this) reference that changes meaning depending on context. Bu he deleted his answer so here is the working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[data-type="name"]').blur(meetmove_address_field_listener);
    $('input[data-type="name"]').keyup(function(event){
        if (event.which == 13){
            event.preventDefault();
            var type = $(this).attr('data-marker-type');
            var value = $(this).val();
            meetmove_map.geocodeAddress(type, value);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The value can be accessed straight away, you just need to use the correct handler. `.keypress()` will fire *before* the character is displayed in the input. Try [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead of `.keypress()` and it should work.

Comment: It really doesn't matter, because I fire event only when user presses enter.